# Problems with add/remove/equals/string-method in MultiSet-class

Tags: java, multiset

This is my class:

```
public class MultiSet<E> extends AbstractCollection<E>
{
    private int size = 0;
    private Map<E, Integer> values = new HashMap<E, Integer>();

    public MultiSet()
    {

    }

    public MultiSet(Collection<E> c)
    {
        addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E o)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator()
    {
        return new Iterator<E>()
        {
            private Iterator<E> iterator = values.keySet().iterator();
            private int remaining = 0;
            private E current = null;

            public boolean hasNext()
            {
            return remaining > 0 || iterator.hasNext();
            }

            public E next()
            {
                if (remaining == 0)
                {
                    remaining = values.get(current);
                }
                remaining--;
                return current;
            }
            public void remove()
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }

        public boolean equals(Object object)
        {
            if (this == object) return true;
            if (this == null) return false;
            if (this.getClass() != object.getClass()) return false;
            MultiSet<E> o = (MultiSet<E>) object;
            return o.values.equals(values);
        }


        public int hashCode()
        {
            return values.hashCode()*163 + new Integer(size).hashCode()*389;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String res = "";
            for (E e : values.keySet());
                    //res = ???;
            return getClass().getName() + res;
        }

        public int size()
        {
            return size;
        }
    }
```

So basically, i need to implement my add/remove-methods correctly, to add or remove elements to/from the `Set`.

To me, it seems like my `equals` is correct, but Eclipse says that in the line:

```
MultiSet<E> o = (MultiSet<E>) object;
```

there is an `unchecked cast from object to Multiset<E>`
Any thoughts?

Also, in my `toString` method, i'm not 100% sure how to define "res"?

Thanks,
// Chris

Comment: How would you expect `this == null` to evaluate to true, out of interest? I suspect you mean `object == null`.

Comment: Well that was a stupid mistake. Thanks! Although, i still get the same error-message :/

Comment: I think my add/remove-method is working now.

Comment: But my String toString is still missing. Can anyone look at it to try and help me?

Answer (score 1):

use this instead:

```
MultiSet<?> o = (MultiSet<?>) object;
```

this is necessary due to how generics are implemented in java.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves the error message in equals.

Do you have any comments on the add/remove/string-methods?

Comment: @Chris - what is your specific question about those methods?